# Perl or MySQL issue

Tags: mysql, perl, select, binding, dbi

I'm trying to code a very simple MySQL SELECT query, as per attached :

```
#
# MODULES
#

use strict;
use DBI;
use DBD::mysql;

#
# CONNECT
#
my $dbd = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:dbname=$db_name;host=$host;mysql_server_prepare=1;",$db_user, $db_pwd)
or die 'No connection to dB : '.DBI::errstr;
#
# PREPARE
#
my $query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $search_field = ? ";
my $prep = $dbd->prepare($query)
    or die "ERR: " .$dbd->errstr;
#
# EXECUTE    
#
$prep->execute( $search_data )
    or die 'ERR : '.$prep->errstr;
#
# SHOW
#
while (my @data = $prep->fetchrow_array ) {
    foreach my $line (@data) {
       print $line.', ';
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

The search field with TinyText. (but tried also varchar, same result)
The search field is encoded utf8_unicode_ci (but tried also latin_general_ci, same result)

If I run the request with a number-only chain for $search_data (like 0124345): ok, I get the result
If I run the request with a text-only chain for $search_data (like AZERTY): ok, I get the result

BUT:

If I run the request with a mix text/numbers (like AZERTY01234) : No record found,
If I run the request with a mix text with dash, dot etc (like foo-bar): No record found
If I run the request with a mix text with dash, dot etc (like foo+bar): No record found

I tried several potential fix but no success.
(changing SQL data type, with and w/o simple/double quotes, no prepared query ...)

I have no idea why and how to get it solved.

Thx in advance for some hints.

Comment: Overcommenting is bad. You don't need three lines to indicate that "this is where we open the database connection".

Comment: You do not ever need to `use DBD::mysql;` -- DBI will load the appropriate driver automatically.

Comment: What do you expect to be returned for "like foo-bar" ?  Every row that contains a search_field that literally contains "foo-bar" - or every row whose search_field contains "foo" but does not contain "bar" ?

Comment: This question can't be answered unless you tell us what's in $search_field -- like Martin says above, if you search for "foo-bar" you should get a result only from rows where $search_field contains that exact string. No more, no less. I'm getting the impression you think "$search_field = ?" does something far more complicated than just look for an exact text match.

Comment: @Anon: ok understood and agreed  @Ether: I'll try removing this call  @Martin and @Ambrose: I tried to search for $search_data, containing AZERTY01234, foo-bar and so on

Comment: @hornetbzz: do your queries work from the MySQL command line ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Perl might be confusing strings, numbers, and arithmetic thereof.

Paraphrasing OReilly's *Programming the Perl DBI*, to help work out what sort of data is being supplied in a bind value, you can supply an additional argument that specifies the datatype when you do the binding.

In your case, I'd try something like the following to force the binding of a text type / `SQL_VARCHAR`.

```
my $prep = $dbd->prepare($query) or die "ERR: " .$dbd->errstr;

$prep->bind_param( 1, $search_data, { TYPE => SQL_VARCHAR } );

$prep->execute( ) or die 'ERR : '.$prep->errstr;
```

Comment: I'm using perl v5.10.0 under Debian Lenny, and it looks like barename "SQL_VARCHAR" is unknown. I'll try a work around and edit this.

Comment: humn need to first import sql type with use DBI qw(:sql_types); for then using bind_param sql type

Comment: After adding this, looks to better work: 
$dbd->{mysql_bind_type_guessing} = 1;
$dbd->{ChopBlanks} = 1;